How to change defect status from Open to Fixed/Tested in ALM via UI? Thanks
Need to change status of ALM tickets. Created a defect in ALM >> Status is Open >> Want to update it to Fixed/Tested. Need to change the status on UI after fix for the logged defect. Need suggestion on this to change the status.

Is this a coding question? I don't think StackOverflow is the right place to ask this. Perhaps try a support forum for that product.
